# How to use Redux in React Native to store multiple values across multiple screens

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

My objective is to create four screens that collect data from a user and then send that data to firebase. It seems redux would be the best way to do this as I am traversing multiple screens. My setup is as follows: A user takes a picture, so I get the download url then save that the the redux store, then they title that picture and that title is sent to the redux store. This is then repeated for a second image and title. I keep getting errors related to undefined objects and calling hooks where I am not supposed to. Here is my code:

Reducer:

```js
import {
  ADD_FIRST_IMAGE_URL,
  ADD_SECOND_IMAGE_URL,
  ADD_FIRST_IMAGE_TITLE,
  ADD_SECOND_IMAGE_TITLE
} from "../actions/posts";

const initialState = {
  firstImageUrl: "",
  secondImageUrl: "",
  firstImageTitle: "",
  secondImageTitle: ""
};

const postReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_FIRST_IMAGE_URL:
      return { ...state, firstImageUrl: action.firstUrl };
    case ADD_SECOND_IMAGE_URL:
      return { ...state, secondImageUrl: action.secondUrl };
    case ADD_FIRST_IMAGE_TITLE:
      return { ...state, firstImageTitle: action.firstTitle };
    case ADD_SECOND_IMAGE_TITLE:
      return { ...state, secondImageTitle: action.secondTitle };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default postReducer;
```

Action:

```js
export const ADD_FIRST_IMAGE_URL = "ADD_FIRST_IMAGE_URL";
export const ADD_FIRST_IMAGE_TITLE = "ADD_FIRST_IMAGE_TITLE";
export const ADD_SECOND_IMAGE_URL = "ADD_SECOND_IMAGE_URL";
export const ADD_SECOND_IMAGE_TITLE = "ADD_SECOND_IMAGE_TITLE";

//Function?
export const addFirstImageUrl = urlString => {
  return { type: ADD_FIRST_IMAGE_URL, firstUrl: urlString };
};

export const addSecondImageUrl = urlString => {
  return { type: ADD_SECOND_IMAGE_URL, secondUrl: urlString };
};

export const addFirstImageTitle = titleString => {
  return { type: ADD_FIRST_IMAGE_TITLE, firstTitle: titleString };
};

export const addSecondImageTitle = titleString => {
  return { type: ADD_SECOND_IMAGE_TITLE, secondTitle: titleString };
};
```

First Upload:

```js
uploadImage = async uri => {
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    var ref = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .child(new Date().toString());
    const snapshot = await ref.put(blob)
    const url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    useDispatch(addFirstImageUrl(url));
    console.log("Run")//This is not running
  };
```

This last bit of code is within my `FirstCameraScreen` class. I have a feeling that this is part of my issue but do not know how to solve it. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your reducer you're trying to access `action.firstImageUrl`, `action.secondImageUrl`, `action.action.firstImageTitle` and `action.secondImageTitle`  while in your action it's called `url` and `title`.

Instead of using`action.firstImageUrl` and `action.secondImageUrl` use `action.url` and instead of `action.firstImageTitle` and `action.secondImageTitle` use `action.title`.

You have to make sure to name the properties the same way you named it in your action dispatcher.

Comment: Okay I made those changes, now I am getting the error: Unhandled promise rejection: Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: Can you try adding  `const dispatch = useDispatch()` and dispatch your action by calling `dispatch(addFirstImageUrl(url))`

Comment: Well, uploadImage is not a react component therefore dispatching this way won't work. I haven't worked with the new redux API but in the old api you could import store and use store.dispatch(action). An alternative way is to return the URL from `uploadImage` and dispatch the URL in a component where you're using the function.